# Merge specific workbooks into one

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub MergeWorkbooks()

    Dim Path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim ws              As Worksheet
    
    Dim wb As Workbook

    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Path = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Data\"
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ws.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count)
        Next ws
        wb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have 2 workbooks in same directory. Workbook 1 contain sheet A only and Workbook 2 contains sheets B and C. How can I merge sheet A and sheet C to my current workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you open your source workbooks and then use the [Worksheet.Move method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.move) or the [Worksheet.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy) to move or copy them into your current workbook.

```
Dim SourceWb1 As Workbook
Set SourceWb1 = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Path\To\Your\workbook1.xls")

SourceWb1.Worksheets("Sheet A").Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

Dim SourceWb2 As Workbook
Set SourceWb2 = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Path\To\Your\workbook2.xls")

SourceWb2.Worksheets("Sheet C").Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
```

If you used the `.Move` method make sure you don't forget to save your source workbooks:

```
SourceWb1.Close SaveChanges:=True
SourceWb2.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

If you used the `.Copy` method close them without saving:

```
SourceWb1.Close SaveChanges:=False
SourceWb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
```